# APPNAME does not have an architecture that iphone6+ can execute

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I'm working on a new app for some time now. I only tested it in the simulator up to today.
Everything in the simulator was fine.

But when i try to run the app on my iPhone (8.1.2), i get this error:

> APPNAME does not have an architecture that iphone6+ can execute

My Target Setting are (Xcode 6.1.1):

> Architectures = $(ARCHS_STANDARD)
>
> VALID_ARCHS = arm64 armv7s armv7

Another app with similar settings is running fine on the same iPhone...

I have already tried a lot of things found with google search, but nothing helps.

Is here somebody else with this problem?

Thanks,
Urkman

Comment: I've experienced this once or twice when I've been building to a 32 bit device for a while and then switch over to a 64bit one. Try deleting the project's 'derived data' in the project organiser, then build again

Comment: @Jef:I allready tried this, didn't help :(

Comment: Do you have Build Active Architecture Only on?

Comment: @ahwulf: I tried both... No change :(

Answer (score 12):

This happened to me after I migrated a project to Xcode 6; the following resolved the issue for me:

From within Xcode 6, select the target, then

1. Select "Build Settings"
2. Under the "Architectures" section, find "Supported Platforms"
3. Change "iphoneos" (or whatever is currently entered there) to "iOS"

Comment: In my case, it is already "iOS", but I still have this problem.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38290077/projectname-does-not-have-an-architecture-that-iphone-5-can-execute

Answer (score 3):

I just did a project Clean (Shift+Command+K) and it seemed to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I didn't notice the deployment target was set too high for the device. Try checking that the iOS version is =< to that of the device.

Comment: `project settings -> general -> deployment info -> deployment target`. This is the _lowest iOS version_ you wish to support.

Comment: The error message is dreadful.  It encourages the developer to search in the wrong direction.