# Running iPhone app on device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am getting this error while running project on iPhone. it i working on simulator. I tried deleting derived data but it did nit work for me.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [APPNAME does not have an architecture that iphone6+ can execute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918385/appname-does-not-have-an-architecture-that-iphone6-can-execute)

Comment: it is for iPhone 4s. Checked the same link. but solution didn't work for me

Comment: Which version of iOS is it running, and what is your deployment target?

Comment: version 9.0.2and xcode Version 7.0.1

Comment: Okay. but you didn't tell us the deployment target, and try updating Xcode - it's at version 7.1 now.

Comment: deployment target is 9.0. But Can I not connect 9.0.2 to Xcode 7.0.1

Comment: You should use the latest iOS SDK 9.1 and update Xcode. Your deployment target is likely fine. Also try setting `Build Active Architecture Only` to `YES` for `Debug`  in Build Settings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94519/discussion-between-user3575114-and-lll).

Comment: No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=armv7, VALID_ARCHS=arm64 arm7 arm7s). .....?

Comment: Yes, try those settings and see if it works... if that doesn't work then the only other suggestion would be upgrading Xcode to 7.1 and try using the 9.1 iOS sdk.