# ProjectName does not have an architecture that iPhone 5 can execute

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

I wanna run my Xcode project on simulator.
My project run on 6s+ , 6S , 6+, 6 & 5s but unfortunately it is not running on 5 and 4s in simulator and show error:

```
ProjectName does not have an architecture that iPhone 5 can execute.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to update Build Settings > Architectures to supply correct value to run in simulator with correct architecture.In defualt its $(ARCHS_STANDARD) //Armv7, arm64 for deployment target to 8.0

Comment: can you share whats writing in Valid Architectures, Architectures, Supported Platforms

Comment: in Valid Architectures :arm64 and in Support : iOS

Comment: it seems you need set valid architectures with arm64 armv7 armv7s

Comment: It help me in the same situation. Just changed arm64 on armv7 for my iPad4

Answer (score 2):

I am facing same issue , you just make sure your device support valid Deployment target

I am using iphone 5s and setting deployment target to 11.4 but after setting up with 10.0 its work for me

I hope this will help you

cheers !!